# How can I use patterns to specify multiple inventory groups ( not hosts ) to run the playbook against?

Tags: ansible

I have several sequentially named groups that I want to run my playbook on. I can specify an exact name or use the asterisk wildcard, but I can't specify a range of numbers.

```
Group Names
group1
group2
group3
```

in playbook
- `hosts: "{{ var_hosts }}"`

Examples:

`ansible-playbook -i inventory tasks/myplaybook.yml -e 'var_hosts=group1'` ==> works

`ansible-playbook -i inventory tasks/myplaybook.yml -e 'var_hosts=group*'` ==> works by selecting all groups named 'groups*'

`ansible-playbook -i inventory tasks/myplaybook.yml -e 'var_hosts=group[1:3]'` ==> does not work . I get the error:

```
'[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: group'
```

My google searches haven't found any documentation the details which patters are legal in group names. Is there a way to use numeric ranges in group names?

Comment: I believe that "patterns" can only be applied to hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

[Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#working-with-patterns) are not *regex*.

> You can refer to hosts within the group by adding a subscript to the group name:
>
> webservers[0:2]     # == webservers[0],webservers[1]
>
> ...